# Prove that $2^{2^5} +1 \equiv 0 \mod 641$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> $2^{(2^5)} +1 \equiv 0 \mod 641$

From the totient funcion we have:

> $2^{32^{20}} \equiv 1$

Thus:

> Either $2^{32} \equiv 1$ or $2^{32} \equiv -1$

**But how do I prove that $2^{32} \equiv -1$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need $$641=2^4+5^4$$

and $$641=2^7\cdot 5+1$$

This gives you $$2^{32}=(2^7)^4\cdot 2^4\equiv -(2^7)^4\cdot 5^4=-(2^7\cdot 5)^4\equiv -1\mod 641$$

Comment: Why did you choose to answer what is clearly a duplicate post, and so indicated, prior to your posting an answer?